# Link style not appearing on Lotus Notes 8.5 (Email client)

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am making a HTML email and testing using [Litmus](http://litmus.com/), however Lotus Notes 8.5 does not appear to be displaying any link styles. I am using pretty old school methods to make sure it works in older mail clients, but nothing seems to work. The links are getting styled in every other client, including Lotus Notes 7 & 8.

Here is the code:

```
<font face="Arial" size="2" color="#00b4da" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: #00b4da; text-decoration: none;">
    <a href="http://www.link.com/" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: #00b4da; text-decoration: none;">
        www.link.com  
    </a>
</font>
```

It could just be a bug with the app, however, it could also be me. I am not really sure what my other options are.

Comment: Shot in the dark, have you tried putting a `<style>` tag just after at the beginning of the `<body>`? Something like

     `<style>
         a { font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: #00b4da; text-decoration: none; }
     </style>`

Comment: Nope, I will try this, but won't be able to get back to you until Monday. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Theorise - did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Put the `<font>` tag inside the `<a>` tag instead.

```
<a href="http://www.link.com/" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: #00b4da; text-decoration: none;">
    <font face="Arial" size="2" color="#00b4da" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: #00b4da; text-decoration: none;">
        www.link.com  
    </font>
</a>
```

Since `<font>` tags are inline elements, you can either nest them or wrap them around multiple blocks of text without affecting layout.

Comment: This should work. Lotus ignores styling directly on a <a> you need a 'span' or 'font' inside

Answer (score 0):

in the inline style, try adding "color: #00b4da; color: #00b4da !important;"

I seem to remember coming across something similar in hotmail and needing to do this but that was a while ago. Hope that helps.